# Imagem ocupar toda coluna

Tags: html, css

Tenho a seguinte estrutra html:

```
<div class="col-8 ml-2 bg-secondary">
        <h3 class="">Ultimas Notícias</h3>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 bg-dark">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/900x500" class="w-100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="card-title font-weight-bold mb-0">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text ">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsum minima minus
                                modi nobis quisquam tempora temporibus? Ad aspernatur dolorum maxime nesciunt omnis
                                reprehenderit suscipit.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Resultando em:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero fazer com que a imagem ocupe todo espaço da coluna, que seria a parte preta escura (porem a parte preta escura deve alinhar com o Ultimas noticias e não sair para fora do card)

Comment: Fala Igor editei a resposta com a imagem centralizando no Pai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu sugeria usar a imagem como `background`, assim ela iria ocupar toda a `div` e não perderia o *aspect ratio* (proporção), se ajustando automaticamente à dimensão da `div` e adicionar o estilo *inline* direto na tag.

Basta criar e adicionar uma classe na `div`:

```css
.imagem{
   background-size: cover !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-8 ml-2 bg-secondary">
     <h3 class="">Ultimas Notícias</h3>
     <div class="card">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-3 bg-dark imagem" style="background:url(https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg) center;">
             </div>
             <div class="col-9">
                 <div class="card-block">
                     <div class="card-title font-weight-bold mb-0">
                         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-text ">
                         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsum minima minus
                             modi nobis quisquam tempora temporibus? Ad aspernatur dolorum maxime nesciunt omnis
                             reprehenderit suscipit.
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: mas irei colocar as imagens dinamicamente com php, é possivel alterar ?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta...

Comment: Pronto. Você pode colocar o backgound inline direto na div.

Comment: Essa opção realmente ficou melhor, a imagem se encaixa dentro da div. obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Na realidade o col-3 do bootstrap poe essa margem.

Neste caso você teria que remover ou criar uma classe para tirar (forçar) a remoção do margin (ou padding).

Use o inspetor do seu navegador para saber qual a margem ou padding que está no elemento com col-3.

Ou use alguma classe nativa do bootstrap para remover. Talvez já tenha algo pronto que zere a propriedade em questão.

Comment: consegui remover a borda, a questão é que se eu colcoar uma imagem maior que o tamanho ele ultrapassa, quero que ele fique dentro

Answer (score 1):

Jovem vc pode usar `overflow:hidden` na `div` assim se a imagem for maior que o Pai ela vai "cortar" e não ficar interferindo nos demais elementos.

Veja o Exemplo. Aproveitei e retirei o `padding` default que o Bootstrap coloca nas `divs`

**OBS1:** Repare que eu coloquei na imagem os tamanho de `height: 100%` e `width: 120%` para vc ver que mesmo sendo maior ela não fica para fora da `div`

**OBS2:** Para centralizar a imagem entre `transform:translate()` para centralizar a imagem dentro da `div`

```css
.clip {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.clip img {
    height: 120%;
    width: 120% !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="col-8 ml-2 bg-secondary">
    <h3 class="">Ultimas Notícias</h3>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 bg-dark clip">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/900x500" class="w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="card-title font-weight-bold mb-0">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text ">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor ipsum minima minus
                            modi nobis quisquam tempora temporibus? Ad aspernatur dolorum maxime nesciunt omnis
                            reprehenderit suscipit.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Se precisar coloque regras de resposividade dentro dos `@media`

Comment: ocultei como eu centralizo ela ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você consiga resolver o seu problema através da utilização da classe card-img presente no Bootstrap, e adicionando em seu css o seguinte código:

```
.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

É interessante ler a documentação do [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) sobre Cards também. Manda um feedback se funcionou ou não, e podemos olhar outras soluções. Sugiro postar o CSS do seu código também para que possamos ver o que foi feito.